# How do I solve a problem with a CSS file?

Tags: html, css, sass, syntax-error, object-expected

I am a new user and this is my first post on StackOverflow.

I wanted to try to code an Infinity RGB animation using HTML and CSS and to get the work done, I followed this video's instructions (https://youtu.be/dxquAfnHhqg).

When I ended coding, in my CSS file appeared 2 errors at line 3 `margin 0;` and line 4 `padding 0;`, where both "**0**s" are underlined and with the message **colon expectedcss(css-colonexpected)** and I don't know how to fix them even if I perfectly copied the source code shown in the video *(the CSS coding in the video starts at **1:00**)*.
I also searched here on StackOverflow, I tried to change my file extension from **.css** to **.sass** but I didn't manage to solve this problem.

Also when I run my program, it only shows me a full-screen multicolor gradient background, while
there should be the Infinity animation.

It would be very helpful if you tried to explain to me what is the problem and how to solve it.
Thank you guys for your time and for your help.
Here is the source code:

```css
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
section
{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: #042104;
    animation: animateColor 8s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes animateColor
{
    0%
    {
        filter: hue-rotate(0deg);
    }
    100%
    {
        filter: hue-rotate(360deg);
    }
}
section.container
{
    display: flex;  
}
section.container.circle
{
    position: relative;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 0 -7.5px;
}
section.container.circle span
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transform: rotate(calc(18deg * var(--i)));
    /* 360 / 20 = 18deg */
}
section.container.circle span::before
{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: calc(50% - 7.5px);
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    background-color: #00ff0a;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #00ff0a,
    0 0 20px #00ff0a,
    0 0 40px #00ff0a,
    0 0 60px #00ff0a,
    0 0 80px #00ff0a,
    0 0 100px #00ff0a;
    transform: scale(0.1);
animation: animate 4s linear infinite;
animation-delay: calc(0.1 * var(--i));
}
@keyframes animate
{
    0%
    {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    50% , 100%
    {
        transform: scale(0.1);
    }
}
section.container.circle:nth-child(2)
{
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
section.container.circle:nth-child(2) span::before
{
animation-delay: calc(-0.1s * var(--i));
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>CSS Infinity Dots Animation Effects</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styleInfinity.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <section>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="circle">
                    <span style="--i:0;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:1;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:2;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:3;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:4;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:5;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:6;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:7;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:8;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:9;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:10;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:11;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:12;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:13;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:14;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:15;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:16;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:17;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:18;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:19;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:20;"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="circle">
                    <span style="--i:0;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:1;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:2;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:3;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:4;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:5;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:6;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:7;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:8;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:9;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:10;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:11;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:12;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:13;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:14;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:15;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:16;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:17;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:18;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:19;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:20;"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We all make mistakes, and Stack Overflow is the place to ask for help. But, next time please describe your question title with more details to avoid getting downvoted.

Answer (score 3):

The main reason why the results weren't showing, is that you wrote the CSS in an incorrect way.

To summarize, `section.container.circle` is not the same as `section .container .circle`.

Could you address the difference? It's the spaces between each class/tag name

Please refer to this https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp to understand how CSS selectors work.

Also, as Kip answered, you had an error with `margin: 0;` and some minor incorrectly written CSS within your original code that I fixed.

Here's the final working code:

```css
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
section
{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: #042104;
    animation: animateColor 8s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes animateColor
{
    0%
    {
        filter: hue-rotate(0deg);
    }
    100%
    {
        filter: hue-rotate(360deg);
    }
}
section .container
{
    display: flex;  
}
section .container .circle
{
    position: relative;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 0 -7.5px;
}
section .container .circle span
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transform: rotate(calc(18deg * var(--i)));
    /* 360 / 20 = 18deg */
}
section .container .circle span::before
{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: calc(50% - 7.5px);
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    background-color: #00ff0a;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #00ff0a,
    0 0 20px #00ff0a,
    0 0 40px #00ff0a,
    0 0 60px #00ff0a,
    0 0 80px #00ff0a,
    0 0 100px #00ff0a;
    transform: scale(0.1);
animation: animate 4s linear infinite;
animation-delay: calc(0.1s * var(--i));
}
@keyframes animate
{
    0%
    {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    50% , 100%
    {
        transform: scale(0.1);
    }
}
section .container .circle:nth-child(2)
{
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
    
}
section .container .circle:nth-child(2) span::before
{
animation-delay: calc(-0.1s * var(--i));
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>CSS Infinity Dots Animation Effects</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styleInfinity.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <section>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="circle">
                    <span style="--i:0;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:1;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:2;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:3;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:4;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:5;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:6;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:7;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:8;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:9;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:10;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:11;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:12;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:13;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:14;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:15;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:16;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:17;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:18;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:19;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:20;"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="circle">
                    <span style="--i:0;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:1;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:2;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:3;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:4;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:5;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:6;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:7;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:8;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:9;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:10;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:11;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:12;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:13;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:14;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:15;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:16;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:17;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:18;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:19;"></span>
                    <span style="--i:20;"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ooh wauw haha! 'an Infinity RGB animation' that was literally a infinity sign animation.  I thought infinity animation in the form of a RGB loop, that already worked on SO. 

Comment: Yeah, I followed the youtube link to understand that. 

Answer (score 0):

As the error says it expect a colon (`:`) replace with `margin:0; padding:0;`

In CSS you open with a colon `:`have value`;` and close with a semicolon. ✌️

Comment: Thank you for your answer Kip, I edited the code but the final result is the same, and RGB background with no Infinity animation

Comment: Well yes that can be something, totally different. The errors you started the post for are gone I may hope?

Comment: Yes, the errors are gone, the "0"s aren't underlined anymore and it seems all perfect, but I don't know why it doesn't work yet

Comment: If you run your code snippet here on SO you can see that it should work.

Comment: Sorry Kip, I tried to edit the snippet and run it, I also tried an online editor instead of VisualStudio Code but I continue seeing and RGB background

Comment: Do you see the changing colors animation here on SO when you run your code snippet? No, then it could be that your browser doesn't support it.

Answer (score 0):

i can see your code has some issues first is you should put colon `:` in margin and padding. Now come to your code as i can see you forgot to separate the classes it should be like this. `section .container .circle span::before`, and this mistake is every if you correct it your code should work now.